# Convert saved PSCustomObject (as string) back to hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable, string-conversion

I have a process parsing out a number of CSV documents and saving changes for later processing in a database. When one row (a person) in any of the CSVs isn't found in the person database, the process saves off that record from the CSV. I currently have it saving as the string output of the hashtable. So CSV document

```
First,Last,Office
Joe,Smith,Detroit
```

The output from `import-csv "path to my doc.csv"` when using the debugger in VS 2015 the string is visualized as:

```
@{First=Joe; Last=Smith; Office=Detroit;}
```

It also expands out to be a key/value set of:

```
First  | Joe
Last   | Smith
Office | Detroit
```

In powershell, I'm able to just use the names objects in the table as `$obj.First` and move on with things. But I'm not able to save that string to a database, and bring it back as a usable powershell object. I always end up with the string literal.

Is there a way to convert this string back to a hashtable, or other key/value pair?

I've given this a try:

```
$data = ConvertFrom-String $raw -PropertyNames First,Last,Office
```

I've tried that on both the raw string as is, which just gives the string back, with the property names in it. I've also converted the original hash to an array:

```
[string[]]$l_array = $raw | out-string
```

Then when I convert it back using the `ConvertFrom-String` command, it is actually shifting the data elements and adding the keys, as values.

Thanks for the help. I can provide more details, or sample code as needed.

Edit
The other side of this, is, how could I store the data that is currently a PSCustomObject, in a better format, that I can rebuild into the same PSCustomObject? I thought perhaps Export-Csv might work, but you can't export to a string. At least as far as I can tell.

Comment: `Import-Csv` produces an array of PSCustomObjects not a hash table. Can you explain what "when looking" means? How are you viewing the result?

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't the `PSCustomObjects` create utilized the same as a hashtable? I'll update the post to clarify.

Comment: @DaveSexton I also update the title to reflect your note of PSCustomObject, not hash table.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called serialization. A straight-forward way is to use built-in object serialization cmdlets: [`Export-CliXml`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849916.aspx) and [`Import-CliXml`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849906.aspx).

The former will save your object as an XML file. This can be saved on disk as well as in a database. When you need the object later on, retrieve the XML document and re-create the object by deserializing it. Like so,

```
# Create simple object
$o = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$o | Add-Member -Name "Attr1" -Value "Val1" -MemberType NoteProperty
$o | Add-Member -Name "Attr2" -Value "Val2" -MemberType NoteProperty
$o

Attr1 Attr2
----- -----
Val1  Val2

# Serialize it
Export-Clixml -Path ./myObj.xml -InputObject $o

# Deserialize as another object, print it
$p = Import-Clixml -Path .\myObj.xml
$p

Attr1 Attr2
----- -----
Val1  Val2

# Look at file contents for magic!    
Get-Content .\myObj.xml
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="Attr1">Val1</S>
      <S N="Attr2">Val2</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: Am I able to make this more dynamic? I'm trying to avoid strongly typed like this.

Comment: @TimMeers Maybe. Could you explain in more details what's wrong with objects, so inventing a work-around would be easier? Objects are where Powershell shines anyway and I see little reason to avoid them.

Comment: it's not that I'm avoiding, it's that I'm trying to get it to act more like `import-csv`. It imports named objects from CSV without know the names. Here I already have a PSCustomObject string, how is it not possible to convert back?